# Div not showing full height

Tags: html, css

I have a html file

```
<div class="ads_list_admin">
{$dlt_msg}

    {foreach  name = fe1 item = k from = $all_ads}
        <div class="ads_i_admin">

            <div class="ads_own">
                {$k->ad_owner}
            </div>
            <div class="ads_plc">
                {$k->ad_place}
            </div>
            <div class="ads_own">
                <a href="{$path_site}{$index_file}?menu=rm_ads&cmd=rmads">
                    Delete
                </a>    
            </div>
        </div>  
    {/foreach}
</div>
```

And the css for the div is :

```
.ads_list_admin
{
    width:560px;
    padding:10px 12px 10px 15px;
    background:#cdc;
}
.ads_i_admin
{
    width:540px;
    clear:both;
    margin:10px;
    color:#666666;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:13px;
}
.ads_own
{
    width:120px;
    float:left;
    padding:8px 6px 8px 6px;
}
.ads_plc
{
    padding:8px 6px 8px 6px;
    width:220px;
    float:left;
}
```

But my div height is not full . That means the background color for the div is not fully showing . Whats the problem here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to clear floats, easiest way is to give the parent container `overflow:hidden`

A better way is to use this clear fix technique, give the parent container the `cf` class:

```
/* For modern browsers */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear:both;
}

/* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
.cf {
    zoom:1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `float: left` on your inner-most divs.  Floated contents are ignored when calculating an element's height.

Since everything is fixed width anyway, try replacing the `float: left`with `display: inline-block`.  This also may be a situation where it is "OK" - preferable, even - to use a table, since it looks like this is tabular data.

Comment: Thanks Annabelle,its working . Thanks for explaining the reason :)